# Rails 5: Many-to-Many Relationship Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I am trying to create a many-to-many table relationship in a Rails 5 project.

One `Shop` can have many `Categories`, which are indexed in the `Shop_Categories` table.

I seem to be missing one key step though. When I submit my Shop form, I receive the soft error: *"Unpermitted parameter: :shop_category"*

I can see my `shop_category` parameters being successfully sent in the Rails server log, but the `Shop_Categories` table doesn't get updated at all.

What am I missing, and what can I change so that pressing save on the `Shop` view form updates the `Shop_Categories` table?

Here's my code.

**Shop Model**

```ruby
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :type

    has_many :shop_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :shop_categories

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_categories

    enum status: [:open, :closed, :opening_soon, :closing_soon]
end
```

**Shop_Category Model**

```ruby
class ShopCategory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :shop
    belongs_to :category
end
```

**Category Model**

```ruby
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :shop_categories
    has_many :shops, through: :shop_categories
end
```

**Shop Controller** (Excerpt)

```ruby
def new
    @shop = Shop.new
    @shop.shop_categories.build
end

def create
    @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)

    @shop.open_date = params[:shop][:open_date]+"-01"
    @shop.close_date = params[:shop][:close_date]+"-01"

    if @shop.save
        redirect_to @shop
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])

    if @shop.update(shop_params)
        redirect_to @shop
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private
    def shop_params

        params[:shop][:open_date] = params[:shop][:open_date]+"-01"
        params[:shop][:close_date] = params[:shop][:close_date]+"-01"

        params.require(:shop).permit(:shop_name, :type_id, :status,
          :phone_number, :mobile_number, :email_address, :open_date,
          :close_date, shop_categories_attributes: [ :shop_id, :category_id] )
    end
```

**Shop Form View** (Excerpt)

```ruby
<p>
    <%= form.label :shop_name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :shop_name %>
</p>

<%= form.fields_for :shop_category do |category_fields| %>
    <p>
        <%= category_fields.label :category %><br />
        <%= category_fields.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :category_name, include_blank: true) %>
    </p> 
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= form.submit %>
</p>
```

And finally, the **Database Schema**

```ruby
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category_name"
    t.text "category_description"
    t.string "visible_category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "shop_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "visible_category_override"
    t.integer "shop_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_shop_categories_on_category_id"
    t.index ["shop_id"], name: "index_shop_categories_on_shop_id"
end

create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "shop_name"
    t.integer "status"
    t.integer "sale"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "mobile_number"
    t.string "email_address"
    t.date "open_date"
    t.date "close_date"
    t.integer "type_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["type_id"], name: "index_shops_on_type_id"
end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I just can't work out which piece of the puzzle I'm missing!

*Update*: Including the Dev log, and the full Shop Form.

**Dev Log**

```ruby
Started PATCH "/shops/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-14 11:08:39 +0000
Processing by ShopsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2qydDj9JovMrg9VT6Lo5xbcNSHl5MH0ylmq3IMMX4iRTAVSgK6JlXWpG+CyuwQK6svZJn9wtnEnZANUlOZYzXA==",
    "shop"=>{"shop_name"=>"test", "type_id"=>"1",
    "shop_categories"=>{"category_id"=>"1"}, "subcategory_id"=>"", 
    "status"=>"open", "phone_number"=>"123", "mobile_number"=>"13212", 
    "email_address"=>"hello@test.com", "open_date"=>"2017-12",
    "close_date"=>"2017-12"}, "commit"=>"Update Shop", "id"=>"1"}
  Shop Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :shop_categories, :subcategory_id
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Type Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "types".* FROM "types" WHERE "types"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/shops/1
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

**Full view/shops/_form.html.erb file**

```ruby
<%= form_with model: @shop, local: true do |form| %>

    <% if @shop.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>
                <%= pluralize(@shop.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
                this shop from being saved:
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <% @shop.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :shop_name %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :shop_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :type %><br />
        <%= form.collection_select(:type_id, Type.all, :id, :type_name) %>
    </p> 

    <%= form.fields_for :shop_categories do |category_fields| %>
        <p>
            <%= category_fields.label :category %><br />
            <%= category_fields.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :category_name, include_blank: true) %>
        </p> 
    <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :subcategory %><br />
        <%= form.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.all, :subcategories, :category_name, :id, :visible_subcategory, include_blank: true %>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <%= form.label :status %><br />
        <%= form.select :status, Shop.statuses.keys %> 
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :phone_number %><br>
        <%= form.telephone_field :phone_number %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :mobile_number %><br>
        <%= form.telephone_field :mobile_number %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :email_address %><br>
        <%= form.email_field :email_address %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :open_date %><br>
        <%= form.month_field :open_date %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.label :close_date %><br>
        <%= form.month_field :close_date %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= form.submit %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be `:shop_categories`, not `:shop_category`

```
<%= f.fields_for :shop_categories do |category_f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You also kind of lost me in the Shop_Category Model part. The actual class name is different (`ShopSubcategory`) and it belongs_to a subcategory? This will probably cause some errors as well. I guess what you meant is the `ShopCategory`join model and it `belongs_to :category`

**Update**

Also be sure to build your nested resource when creating a new form:

```
#shop_controller

def new
  @shop = Shop.new
  @shop.shop_categories.build
  ...
end
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I have a subcategory table as well, but didn't mean to copy the model for that into this post. I've updated the original for clarity.

Comment: Alright, I just tried `<%= form.fields_for :shop_categories do |category_fields| %>`, but I still get the error `Unpermitted parameters: :shop_categories`.

Comment: It would help if you can post the whole form, along with the hash of the parameters that you receive backend.

Comment: Good point, I updated the original question with more details.

Comment: It looks like there is some issue with the fields_for method. It should generate `shop_categories_attributes` but is generating `shop_categories` in your hash. I am not sure why this happens. If everything is set up as your code shows in your question it should be working. I will look into it a bit more and get back if I find anything. I don't think that's gonna solve anything, but try restarting your app/IDE, because you never know.

Comment: Updated my answer. The only thing that might be missing is that you haven't built your nested resources. If that's not the case, please post your shop controller's new method as well

Comment: Added the `new` definition. Unfortunately I already have `@shop.shop_categories.build` there. Do I need something similar in my `update` definition? Still no success, even after restarting rails. Do I need to run a `rake` of some sort?

Comment: Not sure if the chat thing worked so I'll post my response here as well. That's weird. We are probably missing something very simple. In your form inspect the shop and shop_categories to be sure everything works till that point: `<%= @shop.inspect %>` `<%= @shop.shop_categories.inspect %>`
Also in your log I see you are trying to patch a shop, which means the shop already exists. Try creating a shop from the new action and keep the log for that. Then try updating the shop you just created and compare that log with the one from the create action for differences in parameters.

Comment: `@shop.inspect` looks fine. `@shop.shop_categories.inspect` returns `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`. I'm going to clear the database down and create some new shop entries just in case my stale data is causing the problem. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Is that when you try to create a new shop or when editing an existing one? You might also want to follow through with this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1. You might find there is something basic you missed in the process and is not included in your code or my suggestions.

Comment: That is when editing an existing one. Good idea with the Rails Cast. There must be something small I'm missing.

Comment: You should first try creating a new shop. If you try to edit one that doesn't have any shop_categories (and I guess it won't have because the form didn't seem to work before), the fields_for will not render anything. Unless of course you build shop_categories for the shop in the edit method as well. The Rails Cast will clear things up for sure.

Comment: Excellent news. That rails cast, and clearing down my database helped solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes when things seem too messed up you just have to take a step back (or many steps back) and try again. Glad you figured this out! Good luck!